# How to assign event output to variable when testing?

Tags: truffle-test, test

I'm using Truffle test(chai/mocha) and openzeppelin-test-helpers.
Can anyone help me about how to assign values from event to variables in the above testing environment?

Comment: Needs details or clarity and check truffle asseration library

Comment: What's your solidity code?Which events are using? What values are you interested in?